# PySide2 additional window opens only in debug mode

Tags: python, pycharm, pyside2

I'm working on a basic toolkit using `PySide2`. I created a `def` and connected it to a button that opens an additional window, and it actually works fine.. but only during PyCharm debug mode. It doesn't work whether i run it from a `.sh`, from PyCharm or from the `cmd`.
No errors. I verified the code is reachable using some prints before and after `new_window.show()`.

My code:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
add_win_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(win)

def additional_window():
    new_window = QMainWindow()
    new_window.setGeometry(150, 150, 300, 300)
    new_window.setWindowTitle("Additional Window")
    new_window.show()

def window():
    win.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 600)
    win.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
    add_win_button.setText("Add a Window")
    add_win_button.move(380, 70)
    add_win_button.clicked.connect(additional_window)
    add_win_button.adjustSize()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

I followed a guide to create that didn't use `self` to instantiate those windows. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually it was necessary moving the declaration outside.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
add_win_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(win)
new_window = QMainWindow()
    
def additional_window():
    new_window.setGeometry(150, 150, 300, 300)
    new_window.setWindowTitle("Additional Window")
    new_window.show()

def window():
    win.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 600)
    win.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
    add_win_button.setText("Add a Window")
    add_win_button.move(380, 70)
    add_win_button.clicked.connect(additional_window)
    add_win_button.adjustSize()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: This works, but consider that such a "procedural" approach will sooner or later show its limits. UI and event driven programming generally work better using a more distinct OOP approach, through the usage of (sub)classes and instances. I strongly suggest you to do some patient research on that. Also: a QMainWindow has its own internal layout, and should always have [a central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), and creation of widgets as direct children is not suggested (unless you ***really*** know what you're doing).

Comment: thank you very much for the precious information. for now, it's just an internal-only toolkit for generating laravel projects, but i will keep this in mind!